# open() and read() system calls...program not executing

Tags: c, file, unix, pointers, unistd.h

I'm trying to make a program that would copy 512 bytes from 1 file to another using said system calls (I could make a couple buffers, memcpy() and then fwrite() but I want to practice with Unix specific low level I/O). Here is the beginning of the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     int src, dest, bytes_read;
     char tmp_buf[512];

     if (argc < 3)
        printf("Needs 2 arguments.");

     printf("And this message I for some reason don't see.... o_O");

     if ((src = open(argv[1], O_RDWR, 0)) == -1 || (dest = open(argv[2], O_CREAT, 0)) == -1)
         perror("Error");

     while ((bytes_read = read(src, tmp_buf, 512)) != -1)
         write(dest, tmp_buf, 512);

   return 0;
}
```

I know I didn't deal with the fact that the file read from isn't going to be a multiple of 512 in size. But first I really need to figure out 2 things:

1. Why isn't my message showing up? No segmentation fault either, so I end up having to just C-c out of the program
2. How exactly do those low level functions work? Is there a pointer which shifts with each system call, like say if we were using FILE *file with fwrite, where our *file would automatically increment, or do we have to increment the file pointer by hand? If so, how would we access it assuming that open() and etc. never specify a file pointer, rather just the file ID?

Any help would be great. Please. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The reason you don't see the printed message is because you don't flush the buffers. The text *should* show up once the program is done though (which never happens, and why this is, is explained in a comment by trojanfoe and in an answer by paxdiablo). Simply add a newline at the end of the strings to see them.

And you have a serious error in the read/write loop. If you read *less* than the requested `512` bytes, you will still write `512` bytes.

Also, while you do check for errors when opening, you don't know *which* of the `open` calls that failed. And you still continue the program even if you get an error.

And finally, the functions are very simple: They call a function in the kernel which handles everything for you. If you read X bytes the file pointer is moved forward X bytes after the call is done.

Comment: thank you very much. I will address those open call issues, I know thats a janky move. As for the function implementations, thanks for telling me. I was afraid that it would always point towards the beginning

Answer (score 2):

The reason you don't see the message is because you're in line-buffered mode. It will only be flushed if it discovers a newline character.

As to why it's waiting forever, you'll only get -1 on an **error.**

Successfully reading to end of file will give you a 0 return value.

A better loop would be along the lines of:

```
int bytes_left = 512;
while ((bytes_left > 0) {
    bytes_read = read(src, tmp_buf, bytes_left);
    if (bytes_read < 1) break;
    write(dest, tmp_buf, bytes_read);
    bytes_left -= bytes_read;
}
if (bytes_left < 0)
    ; // error of some sort
```